# When integrating Python how much of the version has to match?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, integration

This question is about integrating Python in another program. If I link against Python, I have an import lib named `python27.lib` or similar (e.g. `python26.lib`) for earlier 2.x versions. Apparently Python 3.x has slightly changed the rules there as I find both a `python3.lib` and a `python33.lib` in the `libs` folder.

Looking at the members of the import libs it seems clear that there won't be compatibility between 2.6 and 2.7 for example. **However, can I assume that the import lib from Python 2.7.3 can work with older Python 2.7 DLLs, e.g. 2.7.2 or 2.7.1?** I won't deploy Python along with my application and instead want to offer the Python integration as an option based on an already set up Python.

**Bonus question:** given the name change in Python 3 and the fact that `python3.dll` seems to contain function export forwarders, can I assume that linking against `python3.lib` will work with any Python 3.x version starting with 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patch levels of Python are binary compatible, that is when you link with 2.7.3 the binary will also work with other 2.7.x releases.   This won't work between releases (that is, your binary will not work with Python 2.6 or 3.3).

When you link with python3.dll you can use every python 3.x release, but you're limited in the C APIs that you can use: you can only use the stable ABI (as described [here](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html)).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have sources for the first paragraph, too?

Comment: Not immediately. It is a side effect of the development process of CPython: micro releases aren't supposed to introduce new features and changing the ABI is a big no-no in bugfix releases.  A goal for bugfix releases is to make it possible to update a python installation and be fairly sure that everything keeps working (barring unexpected bugs in the release, and code that happens to rely on the existance of a bug that was fixed)

Comment: You can check binary compatibility between Python versions here - http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/versions/python.html