# Optimizing heavy computations in Python code for package to be distributed (with Numba or Cython)

Tags: python, optimization, package, cython, numba

I have a Python package that I'm distributing and I need to include in it a function that does some heavy computation that I can't find programmed in Numpy as Scipy (namely, I need to include a function to compute a [variogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram) with two variables, also called a [cross-variogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram#Related_concepts)).

Since these have to be calculated for arrays of over 20000 elements, I need to optimize the code. I have successfully optimized the code (very easily) using Numba and I'm also trying to optimize it using Cython. From what I've read, there is little difference on the final run-time with both, just the steps change.

The problem is: optimizing this code on **my** computer is relatively easy, but I don't know how to include the code and its optimized (compiled) version in my github package for other users.

I'm thinking I'm going to have to put only the python/cython source code and tweak the `setup.py` around so it re-compiles in for every user that install the package. If that is the case, I'm not sure if I should use Numba or Cython since Numba seems so much easier to use (at least from by experience) but is such a hassle to install (I don't want to force my users to install anaconda!).

To sum up, two questions:

- 1 Should this particular piece of code indeed be re-compiled in every user's computer?
- 2 If so, it is more portable to use Numba or Cython? If not, should I just provide the `.so` I compiled in my computer?

Comment: Numba requires the user to have Numba installed, but you don't need to (and can't) compile your code to distribute it. For Cython it's somewhat possible to distribute compiled modules (but there's a lot of restrictions on that, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525708/when-integrating-python-how-much-of-the-version-has-to-match but also there are other considerations)

Comment: Actually, my first point looks to be no longer true - it is possible to compile the modules ahead of time http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.27.0/user/pycc.html.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the answer. I also tried pycc (using v0.26) but it didn't work for some reason. Will give it another try with v0.27. Will the compiled version work in other computers with no problem? That's a question I wasn't able to get an answer to yet!